# Выключение телевизора на андроид

Tags: android, железо

Есть у меня телевизор с прошивкой на базе ОС Android 6 от WildRed (Telefunken). При включении с пульта он стартует очень долго - перезапускается ОС. При выключении он становится недоступен по сети.

В этом телевизоре уже вычистил родной launcher и приложения - использую простое приложение для iptv. Есть root и adb.

Можно ли как-то вместо выключения гасить экран. В Linux делал через DPMS. Как-то можно управлять дисплеем в Android на TV?